# Flume agentSink "Unable to load output format plugin class"

Tags: flume

I'm getting the following error and I have no idea why.  If I change the sink to "console", it works fine.  I'm just trying to recreate an example from the flume documentation except across two different nodes.  This is using CDH3.

```
2011-10-20 17:41:13,046 [main] WARN text.FormatFactory: Unable to load output format plugin class  - Class not found
2011-10-20 17:41:13,065 [main] INFO agent.FlumeNode: Loading spec from command line: 'foo:console|agentSink("somehost",35853);'
2011-10-20 17:41:13,228 [main] WARN agent.FlumeNode: Caught exception loading node:null
```

I'm trying to run flume as such:

```
flume node_nowatch -1 -s -n foo -c 'foo:console|agentSink("somehost",35853);'
```

Thanks in advance.